# Do I Install Tape or Valve First on a Tubeless Rim

Tags: valves, tubeless, rim-tape

I've just unpacked a tubeless wheelset and I'm installing tape and the valve. Which goes first? The tape or the valve?

My wheelset is the DT|Swiss Tricon R 1700. And the manual says: "Mount the DT Swiss valve as shown in the picture. Make sure that NO rim tape ist mounted."[sic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked a bit closer, I see these are tubeless specific road wheels. These shouldn't need a rim tape at all.

Just, make sure no rim tape *ist* mounted, stick the valve in, screw it on and mount your tires.

PS. This has complete instructions on page 10.
http://www.dtswiss.com/Resources/Support/WHEELS/WHEELS-User-Manual.pdf

Comment: There is a type of tape on some tubeless wheels: http://www.notubes.com/ZTR_tubeless.aspx. But you need to just follow the instructions provided.

Comment: Quite right Batman, however DTs have a solid inner rim.

Comment: @alex Stans have a solid inner rim.  They recommend tape to protect from corrosion from the sealant.

Comment: @Blam Wow, that doesn't sound great.

Comment: @Blam So the interior of the R 1700s is painted so hopefully that will also solve the corrosion problem. Either way though, if corrosion was a problem, tape wouldn't protect the walls?

Comment: That's what I thought. Never used Stan's, just whatever it was that came in industrial quantities at my LBS, and that has been perfectly fine so far on a pair of Easton EA 90s, also aluminium.

Comment: @JonathanMee I am just repeating what Stans currently recommends for their rims.  Possible the walls are a different material.